# Anonymous users suddenly unable to see block on page

Tags: blocks, 9, layout-builder

A client has reported an issue where anonymous user/visitors no longer can see a field block created in layout builder. This has been happening about once a month and it only affects a single page (same content type). It appears to be a permissions issue, because you can view the block with the role of administrator. You can see other elements, but not the content. Seems to happen about once a month and without any particular cause that I've been able to nail down.

To resolve, all you need do is re-save the node. After which, the anonymous user can see the block.

The site in question uses layout builder to render the blocks. A few bug reports in the issue queue show similar issues that result from content moderation, which is a module we've not enabled.

The site is up to date with the latest version of Drupal Core (9.4.3). I've reviewed logs (server, php, watchdog) with nothing that stands out. And I've scoured the issue queue for Layout Builder. Also I've rebuilt the permissions.

With no steps to recreate or any information, we're kind of dead in the water. If anyone has any advice, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like the block is missing a cache context.

Comment: I suppose precise steps to reproduce are needed in order to provide support here.

Comment: @cilefen I wish I knew the steps to replicate. Completely random, as far as I can tell.  I can pull a database dump and see the missing block on my local setup. As I mentioned, simply re-saving the node fixes it.

I've looked over the cron jobs, which run every 15 mins, so they seem to be unlikely the cause. The logs seem to indicate memory exhaustion.

Comment: One thing to look at is Big Pipe. Commonly, blocks are loaded after the main page load in a request fired via JS, and that can fail for various reasons. Will be worth checking if Big Pipe is enabled and if the block is being served up by it.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Thanks! I tried uninstalling BigPipe, but the content still doesn't appear for anonymous users. 

I also wonder if my assumptions that it's at the block level permissions is incorrect. There are so many moving parts.